# Long to hex String number of characters

Tags: java, hex, long-integer

Hi i am trying to build a random 16 characters hex, to do so i tried a  `Long.toHexString(new Random().nextLong()` my assumption is that it will always return a 16 chars string, Am i right ? (Once it returned 15 chars)

Comment: you should read the Javadoc of `Long.toHexString` to learn what it returns

Comment: Please note that Random.nextLong() [according to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextLong()) will not produce a random long in the range of all possible long values, meaning you will not potentially get every possible combination of a hex string this way.  That may or may not be an issue for you, but it is worth noting.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the mechanism i have asked about, here it is not important the value of the random but the space allocated for it ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the javadocs for [`toHexString(long i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString(long)) (emphasis mine).

> **`public static String toHexString(long i)`**
>
> Returns a string
>   representation of the long argument as an unsigned integer in base 16.
>
> The unsigned long value is the argument plus 2<sup>64</sup> if the argument is
>   negative; otherwise, it is equal to the argument. This value is
>   converted to a string of ASCII digits in hexadecimal (base 16) **with no
>   extra leading 0s**. If the unsigned magnitude is zero, it is represented
>   by a single zero character '0' ('\u0030'); otherwise, the first
>   character of the representation of the unsigned magnitude will not be
>   the zero character.

As it turns out, it will not *always* be 16 characters long. However you can pad with zeros if you want like so:

```
import java.util.Random;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hex16Chars = String.format("%016X", new Random().nextLong());
        System.out.println(hex16Chars + ", len: " + hex16Chars.length());
    }
}
```

You will see the length is always 16 as expected.

And it also turns out peeking at the docs actually helps! :)

Answer (score 11):

Referring to [Javadoc of the method in question](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString(long)) should be your first port of call:

> This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in hexadecimal (base 16) with no extra leading 0s

So no, it won't always be 16 chars.

However, you can print a 16-char uppercased hex string, with leading zeros, using:

```
String.format("%016X", longValue)
```